# Accessing global classes from my psr-0 directory in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a project in laravel and I am trying to move all of my source files to app/src/{module}. I am autoloading the directory in composer.json.

I am having to declare/import all of the global classes from laravel in my files under src/. For example if I want to use `Input` I have to say `use Input;`. How can I access these classes as if the file was in the app/controllers directory?

What I added to composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Illuminate\\Auth": ""}
},
```

The top of one of my files under src:

```
<?php namespace src\proposal;

use Input,JsonResponder,Request,JsonValidator,DB;

class ProposalRepo implements IProposal
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you are using your own namespaces, you will need to either use global classes like `\Input::get()` or you will need to put `use Input;` to the top of your file. At least this is how i solve this issue.